# RSUM - Issue with sorting of columns

Tags: sorting, analytics, obiee

In my report, I've the data in the following way

[image]

The Rank is on the Revenue grouped by Category - RANK(**Revenue** by **Category Name**)

In the Results, the report is grouped by Category Name(By placing the **Category Name** in the **sections**)

The Revenue is sorted in descending order, so that when the RSUM is calculated, the first result should give Top Revenue, the third result should give the sum of top three revenues.

RSUM - **RSUM**(**Revenue** by **Category Name**)

when the Revenue is sorted(in the **criteria**),so that the results are expected as explained above, I'm getting the Rank to be 1 for most of the records and a few records with 2 and 3 rank and so the RSUM is also resulting in the same way.
*If I don't sort with respect to **Revenue***    , *then the Rank and RSUM are behaving as expected **but the records are being sorted by ID by default and this does not meet the purpose of RSUM top get the sum of Top 'n' Revenue**.*

Comment: It might be useful to see some example of the result you're getting and what you are expecting.

Comment: @jackohug I can't share the screenshot of the data. I could try to be more elaborate, if you could mention, which part you need more clarification on.Thank you

Comment: Doesn't need to be the real data, just something to illustrate...  

`ID | Category | Rank | Revenue | Running Sum`  

`1  | AAA      | 1    | 100     | 100`  

`2  | AAA      | 2    | 150     | 250`  

`3  | BBB      | 1    | 100     | 100`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to order by category first (either ascending or descending – probably doesn't really matter), then by Revenue (descending). Otherwise each of your categories are distributed throughout your dataset.